# How do I convert float decimal to float octal/binary?

Tags: python, binary, floating-point, octal

I have been searched everywhere to find a way to convert float to octal or binary. I know about the `float.hex` and `float.fromhex`. Is theres a modules which can do the same work for octal/binary values?

For example: I have a float `12.325` and I should get float octal `14.246`. Tell me, how I can do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's this for? Can you give some examples of desired input and output? Representing float values in octal is a very unusual thing to do. For binary, you can simply use `float.hex` and then use string operations to replace each hex digit with its 4-bit binary equivalent.

Comment: @MarkDickinson for example: i have a float `12.325` and I should get float octal `14.246`(rounded). I dont have idea how to do it

Comment: Thanks for the example; it would be useful to edit that into the question itself. Also, can you explain what you mean by "float octal". Do you have a particular target floating-point representation in mind, or do you just want a value written in octal with both an integral part and a fractional part?

Comment: @MarkDickinson I just need the value. For use as calculator

Comment: How is it rounded to 246?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Oh, sorry for my mistake, it's not rounded, I just wrote first 3 digits from comma

Comment: I have a solution, I'm just writing it up now

Comment: @Frogboxe Thanks for help! Im waiting for solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution, explanation below:

```
def ToLessThanOne(num): # Change "num" into a decimal <1
    while num > 1:
        num /= 10
    return num

def FloatToOctal(flo, places=8): # Flo is float, places is octal places
    main, dec = str(flo).split(".") # Split into Main (integer component)
                                    # and Dec (decimal component)
    main, dec = int(main), int(dec) # Turn into integers

    res = oct(main)[2::]+"." # Turn the integer component into an octal value
                             # while removing the "ox" that would normally appear ([2::])
                             # Also, res means result

    # NOTE: main and dec are being recycled here

    for x in range(places): 
        main, dec = str((ToLessThanOne(dec))*8).split(".") # main is integer octal
                                                           # component
                                                           # dec is octal point
                                                           # component
        dec = int(dec) # make dec an integer

        res += main # Add the octal num to the end of the result

    return res # finally return the result
```

So you can do `print(FloatToOctal(12.325))` and it shall print out `14.246314631`

Finally, if you want less octal places (decimal places but in octal) simply add the `places` argument: `print(FloatToOctal(12.325, 3))` which returns `14.246` as is correct according to this website: http://coderstoolbox.net/number/

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own, if you only care about three decimal places then set  n to 3:

```
def frac_to_oct(f, n=4):
    # store the number before the decimal point
    whole = int(f)
    rem = (f - whole) * 8
    int_ = int(rem)
    rem = (rem - int_) * 8
    octals = [str(int_)]
    count = 1
    # loop until 8 * rem gives you a whole num or n times
    while rem and count < n:
        count += 1
        int_ = int(rem)
        rem = (rem - int_) * 8
        octals.append(str(int_))
    return float("{:o}.{}".format(whole, "".join(octals)))
```

Using your input *12.325*:

```
In [9]: frac_to_oct(12.325)
Out[9]: 14.2463
In [10]: frac_to_oct(121212.325, 4)
Out[10]: 354574.2463

In [11]: frac_to_oct(0.325, 4)
Out[11]: 0.2463
In [12]: frac_to_oct(2.1, 4)
Out[12]: 2.0631
In [13]:  frac_to_oct(0)
Out[13]: 0.0
In [14]:  frac_to_oct(33)
Out[14]: 41.0
```

Comment: Ahem... `frac(12.325)` gives me `10,24631`. Something is wrong, but I dont see it

Comment: @MaxLunar. Ahem, it does not as you can see. Unless of course your locale may be influencing the output

Comment: This "solution" does not work. It gives the wrong values.

Comment: 12.325 should return 14.246, not 10.24631.

Comment: @Frogboxe, I missed converting the whole number, also *should return 14.246* is wrong, it goes to the precision you decide or 8 * rem gives you a whole number

Comment: @Frogboxe, really? So adding a for loop with an if is more pythonic, when was that decided? Try `FloatToOctal(2.1, 2)` with your own code.

Comment: 1) You should use a for loop as it's more Pythonic
2) You should use n-1 in the while loops (if you stick with it) purely 'cause it's giving one extra decimal place than it should.

Also, by the tone of your comment, it seems you have mistaken what I'm saying as some serious criticism. These are really semantic things, it's just that count-controlled iteration is faster than condition-controlled (in this circumstance).

Also, Pythonic does not mean less accurate, yours IS accurate, I'm just saying it fits into the Zen of Python (do "import this" in your code) a bit better.